# Remove items that match memory objects with RemoveRange

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

A Table in database with 1 column(varchar): "user1","user2","user3".

A memory List: users = {"user1","user2"}

Are there any ways to use RemoveRange to remove items in database that match items of a memory List? So that after calling SaveChanges(), user1 and user2 are deleted from database.

```
db.Users.RemoveRange(....);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That standard way to do this with an ORM is to fetch the rows from database (yea, I know it's wasteful) and then turn around and pass it back to the delete function.

A better way is to just to make a raw SQL call (don't forget to parameterize it) invoke a stored proc.

---

```
var t = users.Select(x => x.ColumnName); 
var t1 = db.TableName.Where(x => t.Contains(x.ColumnName)).ToList(); 
//then call RemoveRange() 
db.Ranges.RemoveRange(t1);
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestions.
How can we fetch data from database that match the memory List?

Comment: Sorry, your code does not work as VS says invalid arguments at Contains()
I found this link. It helps me to get match items:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547472/join-between-in-memory-collection-and-entityframework?rq=1
`var t = users.Select(x => x.ColumnName);
 var t1 = db.TableName.Where(x => t.Contains(x.ColumnName)).ToList();
//then call RemoveRange()
 db.Ranges.RemoveRange(t1);`

Answer (score 2):

Whoops...completely forgot the ACTUAL answer.

You want to "attach" the items to the context.

```
List<User> usersToDelete = ...;
foreach(var user in usersToDelete)
{
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted; 
}
db.SaveChanged();
```

Comment: No, the list is a memory object, not from database so we can't use Attach as it will fail because of same primary key value.

Comment: @qnguyen have you even tried it? Make sure you don't reuse your DbContext, new up a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityFramework.Extensions` project.

```
List<User> usersToDelete = ...;
List<int> idsToDelete = usersToDelete.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
db.Users.Delete(x => idsToDelete .Contains(x.Id));
```

However, as you can see, you have to define the key in your code. It IS possible to create and extension that gets the key from EF...but its a lot of work with the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, and is pretty hard.