# IQueryable Intersect is currently not supported

Tags: c#, linq, exception, intersect

When I trying to do this

```
//data.Photos it's IEnumerable<Photo>. Comparer worked by Id.
List<Photo> inDb = db.Photos
                     .Intersect(data.Photos, new PhotoComparer())
                     .ToList();
```

I get an exception:

> NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression
>
> 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ReportViewer.Models.DbContexts.Photo]).Intersect(__p_0, __p_1)'
> This overload of the method #x27;System.Linq.Queryable.Intersect' is currently not supported.

```
// This works
List<Photo> inDb = db.Photos
                     .ToList()
                     .Intersect(data.Photos, new PhotoComparer())
                     .ToList();

// But will it take a long time - or not ?
```

What did I need to use Intersect with IQueryable and IEnumerable collection?

Comment: No, you can't do this on the server with IQuerable, Supporting IComparable would require the query provider to translate arbitrary IL into SQL, which it can't

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547472/join-between-in-memory-collection-and-entityframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the "custom comparer", although it's functionality might be trivial, the framework is currently not able to translate your statement to SQL (which I suspect you are using).

Next, it seems that you have a in memory collection, on which you want to perform this intersect.

So if you're wondering about speed, in order to get it working you'll need to send your data to the database server, and based on the Id's retrieve your data.

So basically, you are looking for a way to perform an inner join, which would be the SQL equivalent of the intersect.

Which you could do with the flowing linq query:

```
//disclaimer: from the top of my head
var list= from dbPhoto in db.Photos
                 join dataPhoto in data.Photos on dbPhoto.Id equals dataPhoto.Id
                 select dbPhoto;
```

This will not work though, since as far as I know EF isn't able to perform an `join` against an in-memory dataset.

---

So, alternatively you could:

- fetch the data as IEnumerable (but yes, you'll be retrieving the whole set first)
- use a `Contains`, be carefull though, if you're not using primitive types this can translate to a bunch of SQL `OR` statements

But basically it depends on the amount of data you're querying. You might want to reconsider your setup and try to be able to query the data based on some ownership, like user or other means.

Comment: Yes, exactly join is right, but I seek a way to simplifying a code. And now I thinking what it's not a better idea.

Comment: You could have a look at [this](https://kalcik.net/2014/01/05/joining-data-in-memory-with-data-in-database-table/) as well, but, in the end it is all about how big your data set really is. This kind of data is typically user bound, maybe you can work with querying data for a specific user.